# VBA Integer vs Long for counting tries on check if random number is equal to picked number at a range of 1 to 100

Tags: vba, random, integer, probability, long-integer

Last week I had to take a test in VBA. I had to code a little "game". These were the rules:

1. Pick a number between 1 and 100 (1 and 100 included)
2. Call function Randomize
3. Generate a random number between 1 and 100 (1 and 100 included) -> `Int (100 * Rnd + 1)`
4. Check if random number = chosen number.
5. 5.1 If true, add +1 to counter, print counter, game is finished
   5.2 If false, add+1 to counter, go back to Step 3.

I hope you get the aim of the "game".

I initialized the counter as an Integer (16 bit). My teacher told me that it is possible, that the counter might overflow. He recommends using a Long (32 bit) so that the chance to overflow is smaller.

I told him that it is nearly impossible to reach 32000 tries on the counter, because the chance that the picked number is equal to the generated number is 1:100.

He replied: But it's still possible.

**My question:**
Is it possible that the counter might overflow if the datatype is Integer? If yes, what's the chance? If no, how can I proof it?

**Why is this question on stackoverflow and not on statistics?**
It's simple. Because you guys know the Rnd-function and VBA behind the scenes, the guys on statistics don't.

Comment: The random function can give you the same #'s back, it's not like taking 1 out of a bag of 100 and leaving 99.  If you ran a dictionary alongside, you could add the entries and then check `IsTrueRandom(x as integer)` being `dic.Exists(x)`something like that.  This will give you something in line with your answer, but it gets slow as the remaining numbers decreases.  I think your teacher is saying you could pick #35 100 times, then #34 1000times, then #20 a million times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this I used in the past for file sampling, bringing the question is a Byte sufficient (1-255)?

```
Public dicGeneratedAlready As Scripting.Dictionary

Public Function GENERATE_RANDOM(intFromNumber As Integer) As Integer

Randomize

If dicGeneratedAlready Is Nothing Then Set dicGeneratedAlready = New Scripting.Dictionary

GenerateRand:

GENERATE_RANDOM = Int((Rnd * intFromNumber) + 1)

If dicGeneratedAlready.Exists(CStr(GENERATE_RANDOM)) Then
    GoTo GenerateRand
Else
    dicGeneratedAlready.Add CStr(GENERATE_RANDOM), CStr(GENERATE_RANDOM)
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description above there seems to be nothing stopping the code from trying numbers it has already tried before, so theoretically a long doesn't help, that could overflow as well, i.e. this could go on to infinity

Comment: That's right, nothing stops the code form trying numbers it has already trie before. But what's the chance to reach 32000 tries?

Comment: What's the chance of picking 99 numbers and never getting the number?  You have 1/100 for and 99/100 against each time.

Comment: Make your own `GENERATE_RANDOM(outofNumbers as integer) as integer`  using what you have, but a public dictionary to keep track of the ones you have.  This way, you can only try for a new number each time.